# Driving from Feldkirch to Munich - what to see along the way

Tags: germany, automobiles, sightseeing, austria

We will be driving a car from Feldkirch Austria, and just need to get to Munich by around 4 or 5.  What would be interesting sights along the way to stop and visit?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately we don't really do recommendations on Travel.SE since they are based on opinions. Indeed what might be interesting according to me might not fit your criteria. Please read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Comment: Pretty broad (and opinionated). To narrow it a bit down, what things are you interested in? ... There are so many things people can like to visit ... from mountains to industry ruins, museums, whatever... and do you have any specific route in mind?

Comment: Not exactly on the way but you could try Neuschwanstein Castle, Meersburg.